# Where can I get threads compatible with LEGO pulleys?

Tags: technic

Have LEGO threads ever been produced? Even the biggest LEGO rubber band is too short to meet my requirements.

I need them for this year's WRO challenge. Note that the challenge only allows Lego products, so I can't just buy the rubber band I need elsewhere.

Comment: Roughly how big of a rubber band do you need?

Comment: Do you need rubber bands, string, or both? If you need long rubber bands you may have to either loop them together and use wheels instead of pulleys, or use Lego [chain links or tread links](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=138) to make arbitrarily long loops

Comment: Very advanced: braid and splice LEGO string so that it has a bit more stretch and a lot more grip. Attempt this only if you need to impress people. The hardest part of switching to a string belt is making sure the knot doesn't cause problems. There are flatter knots you can use you definitely need to research.

Answer (score 3):

There are [many kinds of LEGO string](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/searchproduct.page?q=string#T=A), which are compatible with pulleys, but they are not closed in a loop, but manufactured as a single thread. You could tie a knot on them to form a loop, but the string lacks the traction of a rubber band, so you should definitely consider this if you plan to transmit power via a belt drive made of a string.

Answer (score 3):

Many office supply/stationary stores will sell rubber bands large enough to do a similar job.

I've managed to find a large rubber band 200mm long and 12.5mm in width. It would be too wide to fit on a standard TECHNIC pulley, but you can attach it to any TECHNIC wheel rim wide enough such as [56145](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=56145&idColor=11#T=C&C=11). The grooves on either side of the wheel rim should keep the band from slipping.

I don't know exactly what you plan to build, but you might want to also consider other ways of ways of transmitting power, could you perform the same function as efficiently using a [drive shaft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_shaft).

Comment: WRO only allows LEGO PRODUCTS... :(